# Error column not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5

This is my `forumthread` table:

```php
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign( 'user_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'users' );
        $table->string('thread');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->dateTime('published_at');
```

And this is my `forumindex` table:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign( 'user_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'users' );
        $table->integer('forumthreads_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign( 'forumthreads_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'forumthreads' );
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->dateTime('published_at');
```

In my `forumthread` table I have a `hasmany('forumindex');` and in my `forumindex` a `belongsTo('forumthread');`.
When I render the view it says `column not found`.

Here's the view:

```
@foreach($thread->forumindex()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9) as $forumindex)
    <p>{{ $forumindex->title }}</p>
@endforeach
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: did you define the relationship in the ForumThread Model class?or vise versa?

Comment: ya i define with this code public function forumindex()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\forumindex');
    }

Comment: what is the column in **column not found** error?

Comment: Would you mind posting the complete error (with stack trace etc.)?

Comment: this error i got 
ErrorException in Connection.php line 673:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'forumindex.forumthread_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `forumindex` where `forumindex`.`forumthread_id` = 3 and `forumindex`.`forumthread_id` is not null) (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\new\resources\views\forum\index\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i create again my thread on database without s and its solve